# Nextflow: publishDir, output channels, and output subdirectories

Tags: nextflow

I've been trying to learn how to use Nextflow and come across an issue with adding output to a channel as I need the processes to run in an order. I want to pass output files from one of the output subdirectories created by the tool (ONT-Guppy) into a channel, but can't seem to figure out how.

Here is the nextflow process in question:

```
process GupcallBases {
    publishDir "$params.P1_outDir", mode: 'copy', pattern: "pass/*.bam"
    
    executor = 'pbspro'
    clusterOptions = "-lselect=1:ncpus=${params.P1_threads}:mem=${params.P1_memory}:ngpus=1:gpu_type=${params.P1_GPU} -lwalltime=${params.P1_walltime}:00:00"
     
    output:
    path "*.bam" into bams_ch
            
    script:
    """
    module load cuda/11.4.2
    singularity exec --nv $params.Gup_container \
            guppy_basecaller --config $params.P1_gupConf \
            --device "cuda:0" \
            --bam_out \
            --recursive \
            --compress \
            --align_ref $params.refGen \
            -i $params.P1_inDir \
            -s $params.P1_outDir \
            --gpu_runners_per_device $params.P1_GPU_runners \
            --num_callers $params.P1_callers
    """
}
```

The output of the process is something like this:

```
$params.P1_outDir/pass/(lots of bams and fastqs)
$params.P1_outDir/fail/(lots of bams and fastqs)
$params.P1_outDir/(a few txt and log files)
```

I only want to keep the bam files in `$params.P1_outDir/pass/`, hence trying to use the `pattern = "pass/*.bam`, but I've tried a few other patterns to no avail.

The output syntax was chosen since once this process is done, using the following channel works:

```
//    Channel
//      .fromPath("${params.P1_outDir}/pass/*.bam")
//      .ifEmpty { error "Cannot find any bam files in ${params.P1_outDir}" }
//      .set { bams_ch }
```

But the problem is if I don't pass the files into the output channel of the first process, they run in parallel. I could simply be missing something in the extensive documentation in how to order processes, which would be an alternative solution.

**Edit:** I forgo to add the error message which is here: `` Missing output file(s) `*.bam` expected by process `GupcallBases` ``  and the `$params.P1_outDir/` contains the subdirectories and all the log files despite the pattern argument.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nextflow processes are designed to run isolated from each other, but this can be circumvented somewhat when the command-line input and/or outputs are specified using `params`. Using params like this can be problematic because if, for example, a params variable specifies an absolute path but your output declaration expects files in the Nextflow working directory (e.g. `./work/fc/0249e72585c03d08e31ce154b6d873`), you will get the 'Missing output file(s) expected by process' error you're seeing.

The solution is to ensure your inputs are localized in the working directory using an [input](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#inputs) declaration block and that the [outputs](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#outputs) are also written to the work dir. Note that only files specified in the output declaration block can be published using the [publishDir](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#publishdir) directive.

Also, best to avoid calling [Singularity](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/singularity.html#how-it-works) manually in your script block. Instead just add `singularity.enabled = true` to your `nextflow.config`. This should also work nicely with the [beforeScript](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#beforescript) process directive to initialize your environment:

```
params.publishDir = './results'

input_dir = file( params.input_dir )
guppy_config = file( params.guppy_config )
ref_genome = file( params.ref_genome )
```

```
process GuppyBasecaller {

    publishDir(
        path: "${params.publishDir}/GuppyBasecaller",
        mode: 'copy',
        saveAs: { fn -> fn.substring(fn.lastIndexOf('/')+1) },
    )
    beforeScript 'module load cuda/11.4.2; export SINGULARITY_NV=1'
    container '/path/to/guppy_basecaller.img'

    input:
    path input_dir
    path guppy_config
    path ref_genome

    output:
    path "outdir/pass/*.bam" into bams_ch

    """
    mkdir outdir
    guppy_basecaller \\
        --config "${guppy_config}" \\
        --device "cuda:0" \\
        --bam_out \\
        --recursive \\
        --compress \\
        --align_ref "${ref_genome}" \\
        -i "${input_dir}" \\
        -s outdir \\
        --gpu_runners_per_device "${params.guppy_gpu_runners}" \\
        --num_callers "${params.guppy_callers}"
    """
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That mostly seems to have worked. For some reason using `prescript` didn't work, and I kept getting errors related to cuda libraries so I reverted to my original method. 

There are two questions I have from what you've suggested:
1. What is the benefit of `input_dir = file( params.input_dir )` then `-i "${input_dir}" over `-i "${params.P1_inDir}"` for the input?
2. Could you please explain this `fn -> fn.substring(fn.lastIndexOf('/')+1`? Just so I haven't misinterpreted the reason.

Comment: @Miles No worries at all! I'm really glad that is working. The benefit of using `input_dir = file(params.input_dir)` is that 'input_dir' is now implicitly a [value channel](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#value-channel). So specifying this channel in the 'input' declaration will ensure that your inputs are available in the working directory when the job is run. Note that `path input_dir` is just syntactic sugar for `path input_dir from input_dir`: see [input of generic values](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#input-of-generic-values).

Comment: The 'saveAs' option can be ignored, but basically it just strips out the 'outdir/pass' prefix from each of the outputs. `fn.lastIndexOf('/')`, like the name suggests, finds the index of the last '/' character in the string. If we add one, we get the index of the next character. We can then just substring from that index position to get the [name](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/script.html#check-file-attributes) of the file. A bit like this closure: `{ fn -> file(fn).name }`  but uses string functions only.

Comment: I haven't run `guppy_basecaller` before, but if it automatically tries to create the outdir for you (if it doesn't exist for example), then you might even be able to change the output declaration to `path "pass/*.bam" into bams_ch`. At this point, you might decide to drop the `saveAs` option altogether.

Comment: I tried using the output declaration of `"pass/*.bam" into bams_ch` before and now I'm a little unsure why it didn't work, but it was then paired with my old `publishDir` syntax so that may explain the problem.